# BigQuery extract data for yesterday where date is in the table name as filename20181203

Tags: google-bigquery, extract

I want to extract the data in big query as below 
BigQuery extract data for yesterday where date is in the table name as filename20181203

File are 
filename20181201
filename20181202
filename20181203

What is the best way to do :)

Comment: Check an end-2-end story at https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `dataset.filename*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

The `*` will match the end of the table names, and the special `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudo-column will have values such as `'20181201'` and `'20181202'`. Using `FORMAT_DATE` with the pattern `'%Y%m%d'` produces a string in the format `'YYYYMMDD'`, which matches the dates at the end of the table names.

Comment: Check an end-2-end story at https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6